# nginx: redirect http to https fail when first access

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have a strange problem with redirection to HTTPS on NGINX

- When a user visits `http` for the first time, a ERR_FAIL_CONNECTION is reporeted.
- When the user visits `https`, it works.
- Then user closes the browser, start browser again, and goes to 
  `http`, the redirect is working!!

This in my nginx config for port 80

```
server{
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_sever;
       server_name mydomain;
       location /{
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
}
```

I have checked that server is listening to both port 80 and 443 and firewall is inactive. And the curl is worked for both http and https.

The nmap result also show the port 80 and 443 are open:

```
 PORT     STATE SERVICE
 80/tcp   open  http
 443/tcp  open  https
```

This is my curl info for http:

```
* Connected to mydomain (my.IP.num.ber) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 05 Apr 2018 07:39:46 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 194
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://mydomain/
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host mydomain left intact
```

So, only the "first time" a user visits the site via http, the redirect does not work. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Any luck on this? Facing the exact same issue currently and it's driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

It could be a browser thing the fact that the second time you try it works.
When I redirect http to https I always try to be as concise as possible

```
server{
   server_name mydomain;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```